# Finding Moment Generating Function example

Tags: statistics

Given probability mass function $$P(X=x)=k\binom{n}{x}$$,$x=0,1,...,n$ 
Where $k$ is a constant. Find the mgf? 
It is an easy question but i am wondering about that constant, i find the solution is $k(1+exp(t))^n$ as the formula suggest but the correct solution is $\frac{(1+exp(t))^n}{2^n}$ please suggest how is this possible and do edit the terms used if required.

Comment: Your probability has to be summed to be $1$, which tells you that $k=2^{-n}$.

Comment: Oh i forgot that i need to find the k first thanks